# How to change the color of seperator in tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently creating `collectionView` cells inside of `TableViewCell` but I want to separate each `TableViewCell` with default separator but changing its color. Please help me with this. Or Can I remove all separator lines and use custom `UIView` to separate them?

Comment: yes, you can remove them add add a view with height 1pt to every cell. Did you look at the documentation at all?

Answer (score 5):

Simply update the `separatorColor` property of `tableView` with the required `UIColor` instance.

```
tableView.separatorColor = .red
```

In case you want to update it via `storyboard`, you can with the `tableView's` *attributes inspector* like,

[image]

Comment: from storyboard also can set separatorColor.

Comment: You can set from the storyboard too.

Comment: Thank you for attention, but i created it programatically and never used storyboard. The problem is: I created nested collectionViewCells and one is vertical and another is horizontal. I want that when i scroll horizontally the separator line should move as i scroll and custom color of it.

Comment: What do you mean by moving the separator line? It doesn't move. Its just a simple line separating the tableViewCells. There is nothing like any animation or movement with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the separatorColor from storyboard.

[image]